# External JavaScript not working when it has window.refresh function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, external

So I have a Visual Studio ASP.NET MVC  project. I have a bunch of duplicate javascript in the Views within CSHTML files and I'm trying to externalize all the duplicate code in a common JS file.

The problem is whenenever ANNY function within the external file has this code

```
window.refresh("@Url.Action("","")");
```

then the entire external file doesn't work anymore.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**.cshtml** files are files that use the **Razor** view engine and are **compiled** on the server prior to being sent to the client (browser) as plain html.

When you include a `<script>` tag with **Razor** syntax in a **.cshtml** it is compiled before it gets sent to the browser and contains the compiled information.

#### Example .cshtml:

```
<header>
    <h1>@ViewBag.Title</h1>
</header>
<script>
    window.refresh("@Url.Action("Index","Home")");
</script>
<footer>
    Example Code
</footer>
```

#### Compiled to:

```
<header>
    <h1>My Title</h1>
</header>
<script>
    window.refresh("/");
</script>
<footer>
    Example Code
</footer>
```

If you move the script into a separate **.js** file it will not be compiled by the **Razor** view engine.  Only content in the **.cshtml** file will be compiled.  The **.js** file will be requested and processed by the client (browser).  Therefore, the script `window.refresh("@Url.Action("Index","Home")");` will not contain the compiled `@Url.Action`.

Depending on your situation and setup you may consider creating a variable or function.

#### Example new .cshtml:

```
<header>
    <h1>@ViewBag.Title</h1>
</header>
<script>
    var refreshLocation = '@Url.Action("Index","Home")';
</script>
<footer>
    Example Code
</footer>
```

#### Compiled to:

```
<header>
    <h1>My Title</h1>
</header>
<script>
    var refreshLocation = '/';
</script>
<footer>
    Example Code
</footer>
```

Then in the external script you can use `refreshLocation` in place of `@Url.Action("Index","Home")`.

Note: It is best practice not to add values to the global `window` object (in this case `window.refreshLocation`).  I am using the global `refreshLocation` just for simplicity in this explanation.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I'm not experienced with Visual Studio and c-sharp so I didn't know the about the razor syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Razor sintax in javascripts file.

@Url.Action("","") returns a MvcHtmlString (Html code). And you need to pass at least the action name.

I don't understand why to call @Html.Action as parameter for window.refresh. Can you show the complete function for helping us to help you?